# List Item Timeout

Tags: custom-list, splistitem

I am trying to open/close the a custom list item with 11500 items but I am getting an error which seems to be a timeout error, i checked the logs and found 'Unable to execute query: Error 0x80131530'. I searched google but there's not much of a help. Any kind of help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: > Blockquote
I am trying to open/close the a custom list item with 11500 items What does that mean?
What exactly do you do?

Answer (score 1):

I usually see this when I exceed the lists throttling limit (default 5000 items). When the number of items in a list exceeds the number SharePoint often locks up list when you try to query/GetItems. Main options are that you can disable throttling, increase the limit, or override the QueryThrottle every query. Disable/Increase may be done to the WebApp as a whole or to just the specific list, I strongly suggest you don't disable throttling on the WebApp.

Personally I usually use PowerShell commands as you can 'Tab' through the list commands and easily see which ones apply.

Example:

```
 $web = get-spweb http://...
 $list = $web.Lists["my large list"]
 $list.EnableThrottling =$false
 $list.update()
```

More Info:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg491393.aspx

http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2009/10/27/working-with-large-lists-in-sharepoint-2010-list-throttling.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dinaayoub/archive/2010/04/22/sharepoint-2010-how-to-change-the-list-view-threshold.aspx

Comment: If it is web.config timeout & you have many servers use an event reciever. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you using SP 2010?
2. What is your permission? for example, are you a farm administrator?

Assuming you are using SP 2010 and are not a farm administrator. Your issue might be the fact that you are surpassing the list threshold limit. In SP 2010, when your query result is more than 10,000 items, as an environmental control, SP denies your request. For farm administrators this value is higher; I believe it is 20,000 items.

So your goal should be to modify your query to return less than 10,000 items.

reference: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262813.aspx

Comment: Hi, I resolved the error today.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for the replies. I actually managed to resolve this issue. The list being 10,000 items has no bearing whatsoever to the timeout.

Yes I am using SharePoint 2010 and permissions are correctly set since I am also the farm administrator. Resource Throttling is set to 16000 for normal users and 20000 for farm administrators.

The error came from the lookup list, though it is not actually a lookup list but a filtered lookup from codeplex (http://sp2010filteredlookup.codeplex.com/) which is having trouble in querying semi large items. My reference list is only around 4800 items and its already giving me the timeout error.

Comment: What did you do to resolve the issue? If you can elaborate more, it will help users who have a similar question in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Since I dont have access to the solution  source codes, all I could do is inform the developer. What I just did is limit the view contents since I still could remove some items that are inactive and not belonging to a certain category. However, it wouldn't be a long term solution especially if my list grows again. The best way I can recommend now is not to use these solutions on large lists. It was not designed for it, yet.

Answer (score 0):

To increase this timeout you will need to modify the web.config file for the SharePoint Website.  If you are using the default SharePoint configuration, then the web.config file will be found at:

C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80\web.config

http://weblogs.asp.net/jeffwids/archive/2010/09/04/how-to-increase-the-timeout-for-a-sharepoint-2010-website.aspx